# FQL returns only one element of what I can see in the Graph API Explorer

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this FQL query to get in common paged between a FB user and the currently logged in user:

SELECT pic, name from page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid =  AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me()))

It returns 3 elements from the Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

But only 1 when called via the FB iOS SDK.

Any ideas?

Comment: You must have given different permissions to the Graph API explorer. On the explorer, click on the "Get access token" button and note down the permissions you have ticked there and compare them with those in your application. I think you probably need friends_likes permission or similar.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I figured it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear, my bad.
I was using a different user in my code vs in my browser. Got confused with all my test users and their likes!